# Unable to access Plesk 9 on a dedicated linux server

Tags: plesk

It would seem that when I attempt to access my Plesk admin page this is unavailable. After doing some cursory checks I discovered that the server was not listening for incoming requests on port 8443 (verified remotely via telnet).

I therefore assumed that the service was not running and therefore issued the following command via SSH under the root account:

```
/etc/init.d/psa start
```

This results in the following output:

```
Starting xinetd service... done
Starting named service... done
Starting mysqld service... done
Starting postgresql service... done
Starting psa-spamassassin service... done
Plesk: Starting Mail Server... already started
Starting Plesk... failed
Starting drwebd service... not installed
```

As a possibly related issue, today I experience a server outage for reasons yet unknown. As part of the investigation into this I used Plesk to reboot the server. This action completed successfully and was the last action I performed in Plesk. Since the reboot I can access all services other than plesk itself.

Having never encountered this issue before, and also being something of a newbie when it comes to administering a Linux based server, I have no idea where to go next? Is there are log file I can check for service start errors? Is the solution staring me in the face? Or maybe something else.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Something else that may or may not be relevant:

After rebooting, and before attempting to access Plesk again I installed sysstat with yum in order to be able to use iostat.  Other than that no other changes have been made to the server.

**EDIT 2**

The last entry in the `/var/log/sw-cp-server/error_log` file is

```
2010-12-10 18:35:34: (log.c.75) server started
2010-12-10 18:35:34: (network.c.336) SSL: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

If I attempt to start Plesk with the command I mentioned earlier 2 new entries, the same as the one above, are added to the error log.  I have found some reference to this error log entry and these relate to an updated version of SSL breaking plesk, however I have not (to my knowledge) updated SSL (unless the install of sysstat did this in the background??)

Output from `df -h` is:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              9.2G  5.2G  3.7G  59% /
/dev/md5              9.4G  2.2G  7.2G  23% /usr
/dev/md6              446G  5.2G  440G   2% /var
none                  2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /tmp
```

EDIT 3

As the errors in the log seem to point to the issue that whose resolution is detailed here:

http://kb.parallels.com/8338

I have followed the guidelines in that KB, with the following outputs:

```
[root@s15421692 dumping]# wget -c http://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/12669/Attachments/sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm
--2010-12-10 19:05:53--  http://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/12669/Attachments/sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm
Resolving kb.parallels.com... 64.131.90.47
Connecting to kb.parallels.com|64.131.90.47|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 429868 (420K) [application/x-redhat-package-manager]
Saving to: `sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm'

100%[======================================>] 429,868      509K/s   in 0.8s

2010-12-10 19:05:54 (509 KB/s) - `sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm' saved [429868/429868]

[root@s15421692 dumping]# rpm -Uhv sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libbz2.so.1 is needed by sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386
        libpcre.so.0 is needed by sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386

[root@s15421692 dumping]# yum install sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
addons                                                   |  951 B     00:00
atomic                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
atomic/primary_db                                        | 412 kB     00:00
base                                                     | 2.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Examining sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm: sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386
Marking sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm as an update to sw-cp-server-1.0-3.200811141432.centos5.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package sw-cp-server.i386 0:1.0-6.201004011105.centos5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libbz2.so.1 for package: sw-cp-server
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6 for package: sw-cp-server
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0 for package: sw-cp-server
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6 for package: sw-cp-server
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bzip2-libs.i386 0:1.0.3-6.el5_5 set to be updated
---> Package bzip2-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.3-6.el5_5 set to be updated
---> Package openssl.i686 0:0.9.8e-12.el5_4.6 set to be updated
---> Package pcre.i386 0:6.6-2.el5_1.7 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package          Arch       Version                          Repository   Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 sw-cp-server     i386       1.0-6.201004011105.centos5       /sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386
                                                                          1.2 M
Installing for dependencies:
 bzip2-libs       i386       1.0.3-6.el5_5                    updates      37 k
 openssl          i686       0.9.8e-12.el5_4.6                base        1.4 M
 pcre             i386       6.6-2.el5_1.7                    base        112 k
Updating for dependencies:
 bzip2-libs       x86_64     1.0.3-6.el5_5                    updates      35 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install      3 Package(s)
Update       2 Package(s)
Remove       0 Package(s)

Total size: 2.8 M
Total download size: 1.6 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/4): bzip2-libs-1.0.3-6.el5_5.x86_64.rpm               |  35 kB     00:00
(2/4): bzip2-libs-1.0.3-6.el5_5.i386.rpm                 |  37 kB     00:00
(3/4): pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7.i386.rpm                       | 112 kB     00:00
(4/4): openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_4.6.i686.rpm                | 1.4 MB     00:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           6.0 MB/s | 1.6 MB     00:00


Package sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm is not signed
[root@s15421692 dumping]# /etc/init.d/psa start
Starting xinetd service...                                           done
Starting named service...                                            done
Starting mysqld service...                                           done
Starting postgresql service...                                       done
Starting psa-spamassassin service...                                 done
Plesk: Starting Mail Server... already started
Starting Plesk...                                                    failed
Starting drwebd service...                                           not installed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to put my money on the partition containing /var being full. Check `df -h` and see if that's the case. There is a log file at (from memory so use tab complete if I'm slightly off) `/var/log/sw-cp-server/error_log`

Comment: I have edited my question to include data from the error log file (your path was spot on BTW) and also output from the df command.  I have to admit that I don't know how to interpret that information but if I am reading it correctly there is loads of space available.

Comment: I think yum configured to only install signed packages. Rather than modify yum settings, try: `rpm -Uvh sw-cp-server-1.0-6.201004011105.centos5.i386.rpm`

Comment: I tried that command, but I got a number of failed depenedcies (libbz2.so.1, libcrypto.so.6, libpcre.so.0, libssl.so.6) so I have run "yum update openssl" and "yum update pcre" - this leaves me with one missing dependency : libbz2.so.1 - However I can't find the package name needed to update/install this with Yum.  Any ideas as to what it might be?

Comment: Found it (I hope) - I ran "yum install bzip2-devel" and then ran the rpm command you gave above.  I can now access Plesk and all is well in the world.  Many many thanks for your help